# when writing scrapy pipelines data into database, the error is too many values to unpack

Tags: python, scrapy, pymssql

Good afternoon,
I try to fetch data from web and store in SQLServer. With lib pymssql, the connection has been established. But when process item, the error "too many values to unpack" comes out, so I also attached the MyItem class. I can't see obvious mistake?
here is the code in pipelines.py

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pymssql
from scrapy import signals   
import json   
import codecs   
class MyPipeline(object):   
    def __init__(self):
         self.conn = pymssql.connect(host=r".\\MyPC",user='sa',password='XXXX',database='Webmining')
         self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
         try:
             self.cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO RecruitInformation(recruitNumber,name,detailLink,publishTime,catalog,worklocation) VALUES (%d,%s,%s,%t,%s,%s)",(item['recruitNumber'],item['name'],item['detailLink'],item['publishTime'],item['catalog'],item['worklocation']))
             self.conn.commit()
         except pymssql.InterfaceError, e:
             print ("pymssql.InterfaceError")
         except pymssql.DataError, e:
             print ("pymssql.DataError")
         except pymssql.OperationalError, e:
             print ("pymssql.OperationalError")
         except pymssql.IntegrityError, e:
             print ("pymssql.IntegrityError")
         except pymssql.InternalError, e:
             print ("pymssql.InternalError")
         except pymssql.ProgrammingError, e:
             print ("pymssql.ProgrammingError")
         except pymssql.NotSupportedError, e:
             print ("pymssql.NotSupportedError")
             return item
     def spider_closed(self, spider):
         self.conn.close()
//the code in item.py is as follow
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field  
class MyItem(Item): 
     name = Field()         
     catalog = Field()          
     workLocation = Field()     
     recruitNumber = Field()       
     detailLink = Field()      
     publishTime = Field()

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):   
     name = "xxxx"   
     allowed_domains = ["xxxx.com"]   
     start_urls = [   "http://xx.xxxx.com/position.php"]   
     rules = [Rule(sle(allow=("/position.php\?&start=\d{,4}#a")),                         follow=True,callback='parse_item')]     
     def parse_item(self, response): 
         items = []   
         sel = Selector(response)    
         base_url = get_base_url(response)   
         sites_even = sel.css('table.tablelist tr.even')   
     for site in sites_even:   
         item = MyItem()   
         item['name'] = site.css('.l.square a').xpath('text()').extract()   
         relative_url = site.css('.l.square a').xpath('@href').extract()[0]   
         item['detailLink'] = urljoin_rfc(base_url, relative_url)   
         item['catalog'] = site.css('tr > td:nth-child(2)::text').extract()   
         item['workLocation'] = site.css('tr > td:nth-child(4)::text').extract()   
         item['recruitNumber'] = site.css('tr > td:nth-child(3)::text').extract()   
         item['publishTime'] = site.css('tr > td:nth-child(5)::text').extract()   
         items.append(item)   
         sites_odd = sel.css('table.tablelist tr.odd')   
         for site in sites_odd:   
              item = MyItem()   
              item['name'] = site.css('.l.square a').xpath('text()').extract()   
              relative_url = site.css('.l.square a').xpath('@href').extract()[0]   
              item['detailLink'] = urljoin_rfc(base_url, relative_url)   
              item['catalog'] = site.css('tr > td:nth-child(2)::text').extract()   
              item['workLocation'] = site.css('tr > td:nth-child(4)::text').extract()   
              item['recruitNumber'] = site.css('tr > td:nth-child(3)::text').extract()   
              item['publishTime'] = site.css('tr > td:nth-child(5)::text').extract()   
              items.append(item)   
              return items   
      def _process_request(self, request):   
              info('process ' + str(request))   
              return request
```

Comment: Since I am not familiar with Scrapy, just see the definition of item, it is dictionary-like, and does not only contain one value. So it can't be used in sql. But how to make it fetch one by one?

Comment: In this case the code where you fill the elements would be essential because I think you fill one `Field` with a list and not a single value. Please edit your question and add the code from the spider too.

Comment: I have added code from spider , I also replaced the function execute with executemany() which can handle dictionary @GHajba

Comment: Did you look at what is inside `item['name']` for example? Because I guess everything is a list just the `detailLink` is a simple string.

Comment: [u'TEG09-\u5b58\u50a8\u4e1a\u52a1\u540e\u53f0\u5f00\u53d1\u5de5\u7a0b\u5e08\uff0
8\u6df1\u5733\uff09', u'TEG14-\u4e1a\u52a1\u540e\u53f0\u5f00\u53d1\u5de5\u7a0b\u
5e08\uff08\u6df1\u5733\uff09', u'SNG16-web\u524d\u7aef\u5f00\u53d1\u5de5\u7a0b\u
5e08\uff08\u6df1\u5733\uff09', u'TEG07-CDC\u9ad8\u7ea7\u4ea4\u4e92\u8bbe\u8ba1\u
5e08(\u6df1\u5733)', u'TEG10-IDC\u8d44\u6e90\u7ba1\u7406\u7ecf\u7406\uff08\u6df1
\u5733\uff09']

Comment: Above is item['name'], since the original is Chinese Character, which is not I am concern.

Comment: [u'position_detail.php?id=18477&keywords=&tid=0&lid=0', u'position_detail.php?id
=20870&keywords=&tid=0&lid=0', u'position_detail.php?id=14758&keywords=&tid=0&li
d=0', u'position_detail.php?id=17973&keywords=&tid=0&lid=0', u'position_detail.p
hp?id=21471&keywords=&tid=0&lid=0']

Comment: this above is item['detailLink'], which seems like a list too. and the element's number is the same with item['name'] @GHajba

Comment: I also tried to insert one record, but it doesn't work neither.try: self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO recruitInformation(recruitNumber,name,detailLink,publishTime,catagory,worklocati‌​on) VALUES (2,"elif","dffsf","2014-09-09","dfsdf","dsffsf")') self.conn.commit()  </br> 
     
the same sql statement can work in SMSS

Comment: By commenting other statement, I have known the problem caused by the connection statement.

Comment: @Ghajba, I changed my host name with 'localhost', Since MyPC is not a instance, MyPC is the server name,. Although the connection problem is still not solved because another error "SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib erro
r message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed\n"  come out.

Answer (score 0):

try use `self.cursor.execute` instead of `self.cursor.executemany` in your code.